# listbox Refresh() in c#

Tags: c#, listbox, refresh

```
int[] arr = int[100];
listBox1.DataSource = arr;
void ComboBox1SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    .....//some processes
    listBox1.DataSource = null;
    listBox1.DataSource = arr;
}

is not working,
```

also,

```
listBox1.Refresh(); is not working,
```

also,

```
listBox1.Update(); is not working,
```

i know i can use `BindingList<T>` but i have to work with only array.

can you help me how can i refresh listbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following

```
listBox1.DataBind()
```

Comment: it maybe work on .NET 3.5 and over, for example is there a way to refresh on .NET 2.0

Comment: There is no DataBind() in .NET 4.0

Answer (score 19):

my first answer on stack exchange here.

C# .Net 4.0:

```
listBox1.DataSource = null;
listBox1.DataSource = names;
```

I noticed that setting the datasource for the first time, it refreshes.
When it's set, and you try set it to the same one again, it doesn't update.

So I made it null, set it to the same one, and it displayed correctly for me with this issue.

Answer (score 5):

ListBox only updates its shown content when the object that is binded on dataSource notifys it own changes. the BindingSource object has an event called DataSourceChanged. when the Source is changed to a different object the Listbox will update itself.
Same thing when you bind a List. Nothing will happen if you change the List, because the List doesn't notify that it has been changed. There is a Simple solution for this Problem: use BindingList
http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms132679%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

the BindingList has the ListChanged Event is called every time when the List is changed (obviously). So the DataBindings of Windows.Form objects use events like ListChanged to update themselves. A simple List doesn't support this event.

SO if you want to work with a lot of Data Bindings you should know about:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: But there are enough cases where you do not want to update the existing BindingList, but replace it with another one. Then it will not automatically update, because the DataSource still points to the old one.

Answer (score 3):

Managed to do just with

```
FirstListBox.DataContext = null;
FirstListBox.DataContext = App.ViewModel;
```

Simply loses link and get all the data back to it.

Answer (score 2):

I inherited `ListBox` and added a public method calling `RefreshItems()` which does what we want. Already implemented and all. I dont know why they didnt put in a public method.

Answer (score 2):

The problem might come from the ListBox SelectionMode.

For a reason that I don't know, the databinding does not work when SelectionMode is SelectionMode.None.

A workaround could be:

```
listBox.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiExtended;
listBox.DataSource = myDatasource;
listBox.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.None;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks - looked for ages,.. this was my problem. Microsoft truly suck!

Comment: Yes -- THIS worked! In my case I used listBox.Refresh() instead of changing the DataSource though.

Answer (score 1):

well, without binding I only managed with:

```
this.Hide();
this.Show();
```

it redraws everything...

Comment: It worked and it's so simple.

Answer (score 1):

#### Quick Answer

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = arr;
listbox1.DataSource = bs;
arr[0] = 100;    //Do some value change
bs.ResetBindings(false);    //Refresh the listbox
```

#### Explanation

As stated by [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/bindingsource-component?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8):

> The BindingSource component serves two purposes. First, it provides a layer of indirection when binding the controls on a form to data. This is accomplished by binding the BindingSource component to your data source, and then binding the controls on your form to the BindingSource component. All further interaction with the data, including navigating, sorting, filtering, and updating, is accomplished with calls to the BindingSource component.

So, if you have multiple Controls binded with same data which changes frequently, it is suggested to use `BindingSource` rather than setting `DataSource` property of the Controls directly to an Array or List etc.

Moreover, with decompiling `ListBox` class which is inherited from `ListControl` in .net 4.6.2, the setter of property `DataSource` is:

```
if ((value != null) && (!(value is IList) && !(value is IListSource)))
{
    throw new ArgumentException(System.Windows.Forms.SR.GetString("BadDataSourceForComplexBinding"));
}
if (this.dataSource != value)
{
    try
    {
        this.SetDataConnection(value, this.displayMember, false);
    }
    catch
    {
        this.DisplayMember = "";
    }
    if (value == null)
    {
        this.DisplayMember = "";
    }
}
```

We can see if the value is null the `DisplayMember` property will automaticly be set to empty. And when you reset a value, several initialization will be performed in `SetDataConnection` method which takes extra cost.
In contrast, calling `BingdingSource.ResetBindings` only fires an event:

```
public void ResetBindings(bool metadataChanged)
{
    if (metadataChanged)
    {
        this.OnListChanged(new ListChangedEventArgs(ListChangedType.PropertyDescriptorChanged, null));
    }
    this.OnListChanged(new ListChangedEventArgs(ListChangedType.Reset, -1));
}
```

Although I didn't find the handler in `ListBox` but I ***guess*** there should be less side effects. So I think the highest voted answer is not the best solution.

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

Use BeginUpdate and EndUpdate, that should solve it.
No need to set the data source twice

```
listBox1.BeginUpdate();

listBox1.DataSource = myList;

listBox1.EndUpdate();
```

Answer (score 0):

Windows forms to see changes especially on Listbox and other controls before load is finished is tricky.
To see data as its loaded use invalidate(); then Update();