# Reload Items of dataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a dataGridView in C# WinForms that display a custom items from a table in my database, and I have textbox and button for insert new rows in that table.
When I click on button, the Text of textbox will be inserted into table, I want after inserting, dataGridview can reload new item and display it too.
I use `dataGridView1.Update();` and `dataGridView1.Refresh();` and don't work.

> I know that dataGridView can insert new items, but I want to insert items in my way.
>   it's my code on click event:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String connString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\bank.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            String cmdText = "insert into marja (ayatollah) values(@n)";
            cmd.CommandText = cmdText;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@n", textBox4.Text);

            cmd.Connection = conn;
            conn.Open();
            if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
            {
                dataGridView1.DataSource = marjaBindingSource;
                textBox4.Text = "آیت الله ";
            }

            else
                MessageBox.Show("Error");
            conn.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Can you show us the code so we can fix it for you?

Comment: @JeremyThompson what code you want to see? I write some code to insert new data to database and it works correctly. and when I close form and re-open it, that item added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.marjaTableAdapter.FillBy(this.bankDataSet10.marja);
```

it's my answer

Answer (score 0):

Well you will have to use `DataBind` method to reload the `datagridview`.

Lets say `DataGridView1` is the `ID` of your `datagridview` then use the below line of code after your `Insert` statement.

```
DataGridView1.DataSource = yourDataSource;
```

`Refresh` and `Update` methods wont server your purpose here.

All read [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbk67b6z.aspx) for more information.

Can you alter your code to this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int rowsAffected = 0;
    String connString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\bank.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    String cmdText = "insert into marja (ayatollah) values(@n)";
    cmd.CommandText = cmdText;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@n", textBox4.Text);

    cmd.Connection = conn;
    conn.Open();
    rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();

    if (rowsAffected > 0)
    {
         dataGridView1.DataSource = marjaBindingSource;
         textBox4.Text = "آیت الله ";
    }

    else
    {
         MessageBox.Show("Error");
    }
}
```

Comment: 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' does not contain a definition for 'DataBind' and no extension method 'DataBind' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' could be found

Comment: can u post the code of what u have done...so that it can be corrected

Comment: It's Winform and it's not WebForm

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26280/discussion-between-praveen-nambiar-and-ehsan)

Answer (score 0):

You should try databinding, and possibly populate your data into [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx), you don't need manually call update, all is done automatically.

See also this post: [Reloading Listbox content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15425922/reloading-listbox-content/15426006#15426006)