# I can not sort list with strings

Tags: c#, sorting, listbox

I now I can sort a list like this:

```
_personList = _personList.OrderBy(l => l.Name).ToList();
```

if I want to use lambda,

But for training purposes I want to use a delegate comparer.

My code:

```
    public class Person : IEquatable<Person>, IComparable<Person>
    {
        public Person(string name,int age, string interest)
        {
            _name = name;
            _age = age;
            _interest = interest;

        }

        private string _name = string.Empty;
        private int _age = 0;
        private string _interest = string.Empty;
        private string _cmbShowText = string.Empty;



        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set {_name = value; }
        }
   //Left out some not interesting properties//

        public bool Equals(Person other)
        {
            if (other == null) return false;
            return (this.Name.Equals(other.Name));
        }

        public int CompareTo(Person other)
        {
            // A null value means that this object is greater.
            if (other == null)
                return 1;

            else
                return this.Name.CompareTo(other.Name);
        }
    }
```

sort method: (lstall is a listbox)

```
private void CmdSortCustom_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{               //Avancerad sortering
                _personList.Sort(delegate (Person x, Person y)
                {
                    if (x.Name == null && y.Name == null) return 0;
                    else if (x.Name == null) return -1;
                    else if (y.Name == null) return 1;
                    else return x.Name.CompareTo(y.Name);
                });

    reFreshDatasource();
}
    private void reFreshDatasource()
{
    lstall.DisplayMember = "Name";
    lstall.ValueMember = "Name";
    lstall.DataSource = _personList;
}
```

It wont work to sort the names in alphabetical what am i doing wrong?

The code complie and the program dont crash.

Comment: What you mean with "it won't work". Does the program crash, or does it just nothing with the list. Have you checked your _personList in the Watch-Window, or just in your User-Interface ?

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18404599/3883866): Set the listbox datasource to null first.

Comment: I've created [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5SqdXK) dotnet fiddle from your code. The does the sorting in proper order.

Comment: @ Jesse de Wit  it worked to set it to null, thanks a million !

Answer (score 0):

Like @ Jesse de Wit - told me, i ha to set the datasource to NULL first.